# Clone form and increment ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following form:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Input Button"/>
    <input type="checkbox" />

    <input type="file" id="file"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden"/>
    <input type="image" id="image" />

    <input type="password" id="password" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio" />
    <input type="reset" id="reset" />
</form>
```

Utilizing Javascript (and jQuery), what would be the easiest way to clone the entire form and increment each individual id within, to ensure uniqueness.

Using jQuery I would assume you would clone the form initially via `clone()` and iterate through the cloned objects `id` and add the new id `fieldname1`, `fieldname2` etc. However, my knowledge of jQuery isn't too great and this project is almost killing me.

Any help would be great!

Comment: @nickf: I need to combine and mix multiple values from multiple forms as part of my output. I figured IDs was the best way of fetching these values.

Comment: Also, it is much easier to link `label` elements with `input` elements via an `id` attribute, IMO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) it, and before attaching the cloned element to the DOM, you'd run through and add the number to each `id` attribute.

```
(function() {
    var count = 0;

    window.duplicateForm = function()

        var source = $('form:first'),
            clone = source.clone();

        clone.find(':input').attr('id', function(i, val) {
            return val + count;
        });

        clone.appendTo('body');

        count++;
    };

})();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/8mx35/).

This one starts with `0`, but you could easily start `count` with `1`.

You could also use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) if you wanted, i.e.

```
var cloneForm = function(form, start) {
   start = start || 0;

   return function() {
        var clone = form.clone();

        clone.find(':input').attr('id', function(i, val) {
            return val + start;
        });
        start++;

        return clone;
    };
};
```

Then you would do...

```
var cloneContactForm = cloneForm($('#contact-form'), 5);

// Now I want to clone it and put it somewhere.
$(cloneContactForm()).appendTo('body');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/WZQfX/).

Comment: Is there are reason why not to use: var clone = $('form:first').clone(); instead of creating the source variable?

Comment: @Steve That variable is unnecessary, I just thought I would use it so the selector would be more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without updating any ids:

1. Give all forms the same `class`
2. Give all fields a `name`
3. Refer to cloned forms relative to all the forms with the class
4. Refer to fields with their name

Example:
How about giving each cloned form a different id, and then using `name`s for each input element?

```
<form class="theForm">
    <input type="password" name="password" />
</form>
```

Then Clone it with

```
container.append($('.theForm:first').clone());
```

(or cache the first form in a variable).

Finally, access the input fields with:

```
$('form.theForm:eq(0) [name=password]') // password from first form
$('form.theForm:eq(1) [name=password]') // password from second form
...
```

If the selector lookup efficiency is a factor here then there are several trivial ways to speed it up, such as caching variables with the different forms, caching `$('.theForm')` and using the [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method, etc.

Sample jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/orip/dX4sY

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario `id` attributes are required to link `label`s with their inputs (without making the input a descendent of the `label`).

Comment: @alex - Funny comment, considering that the code in the question does not feature a single label :)