# Jquery Clone Issue with Cloning Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, I'm trying to figure out how to duplicate a form. I was looking at the example from Alex from here: [Clone form and increment ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297876/clone-form-and-increment-id). However, when I click the button, nothing happens.

Here's the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="dup.js"></script>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>

<body>
<form id="testForm" name="testForm">
  <input type="button" value="Input Button" id="button"/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>

  <input type="file" id="file"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden"/>
  <input type="image" id="image"/>

  <input type="password" id="password"/>
  <input type="radio" id="radio"/>
  <input type="reset" id="reset"/>

  <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
  <input type="text" id="text"/>
  <select id="select-one"><option>Option</option></select>

  <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
  <button id="submit">Button</button>
</form>
<button id="add" name="add">Duplicate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
//Dupe form and append number every id attribute
(function() {

    var count = 0;

    $('#add').click(function() {

        var source = $('testForm'),
            clone = source.clone();

        clone.find(':input').attr('id', function(i, val) {
            return val + count;
        });

    clone.insertBefore(this);

    count++;
});
})();
```

Its pretty much copy and pasted from the previous answer. Am I missing something?

[edit] He you go: https://jsfiddle.net/3csjoqb3/. It still doesn't work for some reason, even with the fix.

Comment: `$('testForm') -> $('#testForm')`?
Please provide a jsfiddle so it would be more comfortable and easier to help you.

Comment: I did the change but still nothing. Added the JSFiddle.

Comment: ...Or so I thought. Now it works on JSFiddle at least. Not sure why.

Comment: For some reason I still can't get it to work on my document. Its a long shot, but I'm using JQuery 1.11.3 and the highest version on JSFiddle is 1.11.0.

Comment: What is happening on your end?  Are there errors?  Your current fiddle seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Almost literally nothing. I removed the "#" in front of "add" and managed to get it to trip a breakpoint on load but after that nothing.

Comment: Why have you removed the `#` before the `add`? Consider to use a newer version of jQuery (btw).

Comment: Figured it was worth a try; I changed it back. Just tried the version 2.1.4. Still nothing. I've created the files by both Expression Web and Notepad++. It's like the button isn't getting triggered at all.

Comment: The problem was the code for duplicating the form was getting called too soon. I moved the code below the form and it works great... for the example anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the hash for your id selector

```
var source = $('testForm'),
```

should be

```
var source = $('#testForm'),
```