# Increment element Id upon cloning a row in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML page where in one row has 2 dropdown elements and one text input element. I added a button to clone this row successfully. I added another button for an action POST to push all the dropdown and textinput values to the database. Problem here is while cloning, the Id of the elements in the row are cloned too - so I am unable to fetch the values.

My HTML Code:

```
    <div class="rule">
                 <div class="form-group">

                   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <select class="form-control" name="condition" id="condition">
                    <option value="">Choose Sensor</option>
                     <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>


                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                    <select class="form-control" name="paraop" id="paraop">
                      <option>Choose Condition</option>
                      <option>Equal to</option>
                      <option>Less than</option>
                      <option>Greater than</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                   <input type="text" required="true" placeholder="Value..." class="form-control"  name="value" id="value">
                  </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="rule-options">
                <a href="#" class="add-rule-btn"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="remove-rule-btn"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
                </div>
                </div>
```

The elements cloned are "condition", "paraop" and "value".

Javascript code to clone:

```
      handleAddRule: function() {

      var _self = this;

    $('.add-rule-btn').live('click', function() {
      var parentRuleGroup = $(this).parents('.rule');
      var newRule = $('.rule:first').clone();

     newRule.insertAfter($(this).parents('.rule'));

      return false;
    });
  },
```

I am thinking of incrementing the element Ids everytime I press the add button- So I can easily fetch the elements by their Ids from the POST php file. But how can I increment the Id value? Or is there any another way to retrieve the elements from the POST page?

Comment: What values do you need to fetch, and how do you do that? Show relevant code. There’s countless other ways to select elements, so the easiest solution would probably be to not use any ids within the sub-tree that you are cloning in the first place.

Comment: Your question is too vague, please highlight the relevant parts of your question, which ids do you want to get and increment? which ids do you want to retrieve on the POST page ?

Comment: The Ids I want to be retrieved are  "condition", "paraop" and "value"  (and their clones)

Comment: you want to repeat  "condition", "paraop" and "value". when click add button and remove button it should be removed?

Comment: here example of it http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gS8u2/1/embedded/result/

Comment: Hi Farhan, the adding and removing part is working fine in my case. What I need to understand is , how I can distinguish those elements in a separate POST page , since adding the elements will basically replicate the Ids too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work. All I needed was this additional block in javascript which will find the inputs and append an incremented number to it.

```
count++;
 newRule.find(':input').attr('id', function(i, val) {
        return val + count;
    });
```

Based on the answer here to this question 
[Clone form and increment ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297876/clone-form-and-increment-id)